# Grunt watch warning: EPERM, operation not permitted

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a very annoying problem with gruntjs and `grunt-contrib-watch` plugin. After some time, I can not define, it may be half an hour or two hours of work (it's random) the console spits out this error:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...Warning: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\dev\project\app\index.html~RF97bf99.TMP'
```

it repeats ~50 times, and next this:

```
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a templat
e (Maximum call stack size exceeded).).
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a templat
e (An error occurred while processing a template (Maximum call stack size exceeded).).).
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a templat
e (An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a template (Max
imum call stack size exceeded).).).).
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a templat
e (An error occurred while processing a template (An error occurred while processing a template (An
error occurred while processing a template (Maximum call stack size exceeded).).).).).
```

My Grunfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    // Show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        // Project settings
        project: {
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            src: 'bower_components/sass-bootstrap',
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('bower_components/sass-bootstrap/package.json'),
            banner: '/*!\n' +
                    ' * Bootstrap v<%= bootstrap.pkg.version %> by @fat and @mdo\n' +
                    ' * Copyright <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= bootstrap.pkg.author %>\n' +
                    ' * Licensed under <%= _.pluck(bootstrap.pkg.licenses, "url").join(", ") %>\n' +
                    ' *\n' +
                    ' * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.\n' +
                    ' */\n\n',
            jqueryCheck: 'if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") { throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery") }\n\n'
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= project.app %>/sass/{,*/}*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dev', 'autoprefixer'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true
                },
            },
            js: {
                files: [
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/{,*/}*.js',
                    '!<%= project.app %>/js/vendor/{,*/}*.js',
                    '!<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/{,*/}*.js'
                ],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= project.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= project.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= project.app %>'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= project.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: ['<%= bootstrap.src %>/lib/']
            },
            dev: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/app.css': '<%= project.app %>/sass/app.scss'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/app.css': '<%= project.app %>/sass/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 2 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/css/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '<%= project.app %>/css/'
                }]
            }
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                nonull: true,
                separator: '\n\n'
            },
            bootstrap: {
                options: {
                    banner: '<%= bootstrap.banner %><%= bootstrap.jqueryCheck %>'
                },
                src: [
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/transition.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/alert.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/button.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/carousel.js',
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/collapse.js',
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/dropdown.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/modal.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/tooltip.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/popover.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/scrollspy.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/tab.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/affix.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.js'
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins.js': ['<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js', '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/*.min.js']
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            bootstrap: {
                options: {
                    banner: '<%= bootstrap.banner %>'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js': '<%= concat.bootstrap.dest %>'
                }
            },
            all: {
                options: {
                    preserveComments: 'some',
                    report: 'min'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/js/',
                    src: ['*.js', '!plugins.js'],
                    ext: '.min.js',
                    dest: '<%= project.app %>/js/'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                report: 'min'
            },
            dist: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= project.app %>/css/',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: '<%= cssmin.dist.cwd %>',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/img',
                    src: ['{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'],
                    dest: '<%= project.dist %>/img'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // Register tasks
    // ==================================================

    // Run local server
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    // Build JS
    grunt.registerTask('build-js', [
        'concat:bootstrap',
        'uglify',
        'concat:plugins'
    ]);

    // Build CSS
    grunt.registerTask('build-css', [
        'sass:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'cssmin'
    ]);

    // Minify images
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['imagemin']);

    // grunt.registerTask('default', ['']);

};
```

package.json (all dependencies are up to date):

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.1",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.6",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.9.0",
    "jpegtran-bin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.4.0"
  }
}
```

I'm on Windows 7 32-bit, gruntjs v.0.4.2, nodejs v0.10.22. Any ideas what may causes this problem? And how would I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem "EPERM, operation not permitted..." and it was because i didn't opened the CMD in administrator mode.
So right click on CMD and run as administrator.
This solved my error.

Comment: I just had the same problem on a Linux Mint. Running the grunt task with `sudo` worked.

Comment: this should most likely be the accepted answer, worked well for me and solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Just running anything that errors with superuser permissions is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this problem, but I think it might have something to do with the way you're using wildcards on your `Gruntfile.js`. A co-worker once complained that his `watch` task was taking an incredible amount of time to run, up to 3-4 minutes a time. He was using the syntax:

```
/css/{,*/}*.css
```

I didn't have that problem, so while making his `Gruntfile.js` more like mine, we found out that using:

```
/css/**/*.css
```

...solved the whole problem! All his tasks ran at *less than 10 seconds*.

I have made changes to your `Gruntfile.js`, you might want to use a `diff` tool to compare my version to yours and see what was changed.

I would also strongly recommend using `jshint` to lint the `JavaScript` in your project, specially the `Gruntfile.js` and any other configuration file important to `Grunt` you might have detached from your `Gruntfile.js`. [An example here](https://github.com/dreamyguy/color-consolidator/blob/master/config/jshint.js) (look around the same project for more detail).

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    // Show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        // Project settings
        project: {
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            src: 'bower_components/sass-bootstrap',
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('bower_components/sass-bootstrap/package.json'),
            banner: '/*!\n' +
                    ' * Bootstrap v<%= bootstrap.pkg.version %> by @fat and @mdo\n' +
                    ' * Copyright <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= bootstrap.pkg.author %>\n' +
                    ' * Licensed under <%= _.pluck(bootstrap.pkg.licenses, "url").join(", ") %>\n' +
                    ' *\n' +
                    ' * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.\n' +
                    ' */\n\n',
            jqueryCheck: 'if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") { throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery") }\n\n'
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= project.app %>/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dev', 'autoprefixer'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true
                },
            },
            js: {
                files: [
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/**/*.js',
                    '!<%= project.app %>/js/vendor/**/*.js',
                    '!<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/**/*.js'
                ],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= project.app %>/**/*.html',
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/**/*.css',
                    '<%= project.app %>/images/**/*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= project.app %>'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= project.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: ['<%= bootstrap.src %>/lib/']
            },
            dev: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/app.css': '<%= project.app %>/sass/app.scss'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/css/app.css': '<%= project.app %>/sass/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 2 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/css',
                    src: '/**/*.css',
                    dest: '<%= project.app %>/css'
                }]
            }
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                nonull: true,
                separator: '\n\n'
            },
            bootstrap: {
                options: {
                    banner: '<%= bootstrap.banner %><%= bootstrap.jqueryCheck %>'
                },
                src: [
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/transition.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/alert.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/button.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/carousel.js',
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/collapse.js',
                    '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/dropdown.js'
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/modal.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/tooltip.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/popover.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/scrollspy.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/tab.js',
                    // '<%= bootstrap.src %>/js/affix.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.js'
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins.js': ['<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js', '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/*.min.js']
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            bootstrap: {
                options: {
                    banner: '<%= bootstrap.banner %>'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= project.app %>/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js': '<%= concat.bootstrap.dest %>'
                }
            },
            all: {
                options: {
                    preserveComments: 'some',
                    report: 'min'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/js/',
                    src: ['*.js', '!plugins.js'],
                    ext: '.min.js',
                    dest: '<%= project.app %>/js/'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                report: 'min'
            },
            dist: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= project.app %>/css/',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: '<%= cssmin.dist.cwd %>',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= project.app %>/img',
                    src: ['/**/*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'],
                    dest: '<%= project.dist %>/img'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // Register tasks
    // ==================================================

    // Run local server
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    // Build JS
    grunt.registerTask('build-js', [
        'concat:bootstrap',
        'uglify',
        'concat:plugins'
    ]);

    // Build CSS
    grunt.registerTask('build-css', [
        'sass:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'cssmin'
    ]);

    // Minify images
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['imagemin']);

    // grunt.registerTask('default', ['']);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

On linux, change  directory permissions

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 name_directory
```